# Sample and population central moments

Tags: probability, statistics

Given that the population central moment is defined as:

$$\mu_k = E[(X-\mu)^k]$$

and the sample population moment:

$$\hat{\mu_k}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i-\hat{m_1})^k$$

where $\hat{m_1}$ is the sample mean: $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i$

How does one show that the expected value of the sample's central moment, say for $k=2$ is:

$$E[\hat{\mu_2}]=\frac{N-1}{N}\mu_2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the expected value to the sample central moment

$$E\left[\hat{\mu_2}\right] =E\left[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i-\hat{m_1})^2\right] = \\
=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N E\left[(x_i-\hat{m_1})^2\right] 
= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \left\{E\left[x_i^2\right]+E\left[\hat{m_1}^2\right]-E\left[2x_i\hat{m_1}\right]\right\}.$$

In particular, you have that:
$$E\left[x_i^2\right] = E[X^2],$$

$$E\left[\hat{m_1}^2\right] = \frac{1}{N^2}E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\right)^2\right] = \\
= \frac{1}{N^2}E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^Nx_j\right)\right] = \frac{1}{N^2}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N x_i x_j\right] = \\ 
= \frac{1}{N^2}\left\{\sum_{i=1}^N E\left[x_i^2\right] + \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1, j \neq i}^N E\left[x_i] E[x_j\right]\right\} = \frac{1}{N}\left\{E\left[X^2\right] + (N-1)E\left[X\right]^2\right\},$$

and

$$E\left[2x_i\hat{m_1}\right] = \frac{1}{N}E\left[2\sum_{j=1}^Nx_j x_i\right] = \frac{1}{N}\left\{E\left[2x_i^2\right] + 2\sum_{j=1, j \neq i}^N E\left[x_j] E[x_i\right]\right\} = \frac{1}{N}\left\{2E[X^2] + 2(N-1)E[X]^2\right\}.
$$

Finally:

$$E\left[\hat{\mu_2}\right] = \\
= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\left\{E[X^2] + \frac{1}{N}\left\{E\left[X^2\right] + (N-1)E\left[X\right]^2\right\} - \frac{1}{N}\left\{2E[X^2] + 2(N-1)E[X]^2\right\}\right\} = \\
= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\left\{E[X^2]\left[1 + \frac{1}{N}-\frac{2}{N}\right] + E[X]^2\left[\frac{(N-1)}{N} - 2\frac{N-1}{N}\right]\right\} = \\
= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{N-1}{N} \left\{E[X^2] - E[X]^2\right\} 
= \frac{N-1}{N} \mu_2. $$

Comment: I thought that $E[\hat{m_1^2}]=E[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2]$

Comment: Obviously, $E[\hat{m_1^2}]=E[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2]$ is incorrect.

Comment: .... you are right

Comment: what do these curly brackets mean? {}

Comment: Also not sure how you go from $\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1, j \neq i}^N E\left[x_i] E[x_j\right]$ to $(N-1)E\left[X\right]^2$

Comment: I think I got the above. But still, what are the curly brackets here

Comment: Sorry for the curly brackets. They have no particular meaning. Think about them like standard brackets ( and ).